# In VIM, is it possible to use the selected text in the substitute clause without retyping it?

Tags: vim, substitution

Let's say I have a word selected in visual mode.  I would like to perform a substitution on that word and all other instances of that word in a file by using s//.  Is there a way to use the highlighted text in the `s/<here>/stuff/` part without having to retype it?

Comment: I've always found it irksome that the vim command line doesn't have access to any registers, etc.

Comment: I agree 100% with that.  That would make a huge difference.

Comment: @inkedmn: What do you mean it doesn't have access to registers? ctrl-r clearly allows you to access copy/paste registers.

Comment: @depesz: I had no idea - you've just made my day

Comment: @inkedmn: ah :) good to know. Generally - if there is something to make programmer life easier - vim most likely has a way to do it.

Comment: Now to make my life easier...  :s/pls send me teh codez/<ctrl-r>codez/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sure. If you selected the word, just "y"ank it, and then type:

```
:%s/<ctrl-r>"/something else/g
```

Where  is pressing ctrl key with r key, and " is just " character.

All keypresses:

```
y:%s/<ctrl-r>"/what to put/g<enter>
```

Comment: Wow, cool! Where can I find that trick in the vim documentation?

Comment: Not sure. Ctrl-r is pretty well known thing.

Answer (score 4):

If you searched for your text before you can use

> CTRL-R /

to insert the last search item in your search and replace string.

You can check this page for other similar tricks:

http://www.vim.org/htmldoc/insert.html

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to yank the word, place your cursor on the word and then:

```
:%s/<C-r><C-w>/bar/g
```

Comment: Sweet!  That is another one I was curious about!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to access register contents from the command line is via `@` variables.  So if you yank text into the default register, it'll be in a variable called `@"`.

```
:exe '%s/' . @" . '/stuff/'
```

Here's a mapping to make this easy to type:

```
vmap <Leader>s y:exe '%s/' . @" . '//g'<Left><Left><Left>
```

Now you can highlight something in visual mode, type `\s`, type your replacement and hit `Enter`.  [depesz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80168/depesz)'s version also makes a good mapping (almost exactly as he typed it):

```
vmap <Leader>s y:%s/<c-r>"//g<Left><Left>
```