# vim - search current line equivalent to search current word

Tags: vim, editor

Is there a equivalent to search the string in the current line similar to `*` or `#` which search the current word?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691784/vim-substitution-using-the-current-line-as-the-search-string one of the answers has the command do perform line search & replace, just remove the replace part

Comment: Do you mean search the current line in your file or search a string in the current line?

Comment: @Ekans The whole current line. it can has multiple words.

Comment: Note: There is a [dedicated site for vi & vim](http://vi.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but it's easy to make it.

```
:nnoremap <silent> <Leader>f :execute '/\V\^' . escape(getline('.'), '\\/') . '\$'<CR>
```

This should give you `\f` (or whatever you remapped as leader instead of the backslash) that should start the search for the next instance of the current line.

Comment: kind of duplicated with yours, removed mine. maybe we could add `\^` and `\$` at the beginning and end of the line. to make sure only search by line unit. E.g. one line has 7 `a`, the other has 70 `a`s